# Can we call a method at class level rather than in a method?

Tags: java

Can someone please tell me, how to call a method at class level?

Suppose I have a class like below, then can we call test1Method at class level? If it is not correct please tell me the reason..

```
class Test2 {

Test1 t1=new Test1();
t1.test1Method();

public void test2Method() {  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "at the class level"? "Class" methods are static, and may be called on the class itself, or an instance (including a `null`). The reason? Because that's how Java is.

Comment: @Bobby: Ok..will follow that from my next post.Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't have method invocation statement or any other statement directly under a class. As specified in [JLS Section 8 - Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html):

> The body of a class declares members (fields and methods and nested classes and interfaces), instance and static initializers, and constructors (§8.1.6).

You have to move the method invocation in either of those member (some method), initializer or constructor.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. I mean to point the members, initializers, and constructors collectively, as specified in the JLS Section.

Answer (score 3):

You can call them within an [instance block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

```
class Test2 {

{
  Test1 t1=new Test1();
  t1.test1Method();
}

}
```

the **instance** or **initializer block** will be called every time an object of type `Test2` is constructed. JVM makes sure that the instance block contents are copied within the constructor, like below

```
class Test2 {

     public Test2() {
        {
           Test1 t1=new Test1();
           t1.test1Method();
       }
     }    

}
```

OR [static initialization block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

```
class Test2 {

static {
  Test1 t1=new Test1();
  t1.test1Method();
}

}
```

the **static block** is executed when first time the class `Test2` gets loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the return type of the test1Method method, then you can return Test1 object with the method and write your code like below.

```
class Test2 {

Test1 t1=new Test1().test1Method();

public void test2Method() {  }

}
```